# How to enable debug mode during starting Centos 7 or Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, login

Does anyone know how to enable debug mode during starting Centos 7 or Centos 6.5? 
I mean when any login issue comes for start Centos and we need to doing troubleshoot for the reason.

Appreciate much for any adivce.

Answer (score 1):

for CentOS 7 you can use journald to get error messages during startup, messages will get removed after server reboot, if you want to keep them or have a easy access create the following folder

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/journal 
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
sudo  systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad,
Got, thanks lot and I will try it in my Centos 7.
I really appreciate your answer.